# Contrained type familly

Tags: haskell, type-families

I have the following type family in haskell :

```hs
type family Foo (a :: Bar) :: * where
```

followed by a bunch of equality. I want to put a constraint on the kind return to ensure they're all instance of a typeclass. How can i do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Haskell, it's better not to do that. (See also the desire to put constraints on type variables in data declarations.) You should put constraints where they're actually going to be used. That will still get called out during type checking if it's missing when it's needed, but it will allow things that don't need it to be more flexible.

Comment: There can actually be good reasons for putting constraints somewhere else from where they're actually needed (mostly related to maintainability).

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer, I needed to use FlexibleContext

Answer (score 4):

Seems like you're looking for

```
class (YourConstraint (Foo a)) => Fooish (a :: Bar) where
  type Foo a :: Type
```

As Carl noted, this is somewhat analogous to the old data declaration style with

```
data C a => D a = D ...
```

which is widely considered a bad idea because it's not possible to *use* the constraint, all it accomplishes is preventing to build values that don't obey the constraint.

But unlike those data declarations, a constraint to an associated type family *is* useful IMO, because there's an easy way to get at the constrait whenever it's needed: you just need to mention `Fooish`.